# How to replicate in @media

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some css which works in mobile but not sure how to make it work in desktop.As in mobile view, `Post an Event` and `Find an Event` should be listed on the same line below `Events.`

This css makes the layout work in mobile:

```css
.event {
float :right;
} 

.findanevent 
 br {
 display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="lasvegas">Events</div>
<div class="findanevent"></div>
<div class="event_wrapper"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event">
<span id="findanevent" class="event">Find an Event</span>.</a>
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/"><span id="postanevent" class="event">Post an Event</span></a></div>
```

Page: https://adsler.co.uk/events/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? Please try making your question clearer and more detailed so you can be better helped.

```css
.event {
float :right;
} 

.findanevent 
 display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="lasvegas">Events</div>
<div class="findanevent"></div>
<div class="event_wrapper"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event">
<span id="findanevent" class="event">Find an Event</span></a>
<br>
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/"><span id="postanevent" class="event">Post an Event</span></a></div>
```

Comment: Hi. So if you view this page in mobile, https://adsler.co.uk/events / i want to look like that in desktop please, including the same font,, layout.... Etc